# solution for ui component that combine text input and dropdown

Tags: semantic-ui

Is there a semantic-ui ready-to-use solution for ui component that combine text input and dropdown of predefined values. The sample is "A dropdown menu can appear to be floating below an element" (http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html), but it would be text input instead of button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ContentEditable Solution:**

Try using the new html5 element, "contenteditable".

e.g.
Original standard Semantic UI code:

```
  <div class="ui selection dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="gender">
    <div class="default text">gender</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item" data-value="Male">Male</div>
      <div class="item" data-value="Female">Female</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

New Modified Code with contenteditable:

```
  <div class="ui selection dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="gender">
    <div class="text" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item" data-value="Male">Male</div>
      <div class="item" data-value="Female">Female</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Notice 3rd line is modified in several ways.
I removed the "default" class since I don't want the grey placeholder effect.
I added contenteditable attribute.
And I also removed the placeholder text.

Now you need a JQuery event handler that handles that div's onChange event, or the form's submit's button click event so that you can copy the div's value to the hidden text input.

**Datalist HTML5 Solution**:

If you strictly don't need the dropdown styling semantic UI provides, such as option dividers, then you can use:

```
<div class="ui input">
  <input list="browsers" type="text">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
</div>
```